# Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ a lattice?

Tags: integer-lattices

Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$?

How to prove that?

Comment: please recall the definition

Answer (score 5):

No. It fails to be discrete. In fact $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

It suffices to observe that the sequence $(\sqrt 2-1)^n\in \mathbb Z[\sqrt 2] $ converges to $0$.

Comment: How to show that it is not discrete.

Comment: @Nemo, what's your definition of discrete? One definition is that there exists an constant $\delta > 0$ such that no two members of the set are closer than $\delta$ together. That definition is violated here, as the example given by Hagen demonstrates.

Comment: @simon: Your definition is correct, and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is not a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ (therefore, not a lattice), as Hagen showed.